# cts query to select only a field from json document in Marklogic staging

Tags: javascript, marklogic

I'm trying to write a javaScript cts query to query a key from a json document based on another key. i.e, similar to a query like select name from data-hub-staging where source='source1'

```
{
    "source": "source1",
    "name": "John",
    "DOB": "1-01-1990",
    "load_date": "2021-10-23 10:23:55"
}
```

I have been trying the below query but it returns all the fields, I wanted only the name field.

```
const query = cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery(
              "source",
              "source1");

cts.search(query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `cts.search` is to run a search that returns entire documents. The `cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery` identifies a criterion for selecting a document. After you've run the search, you'll be able to pull out whatever you'd like from that document. I think this should do it:

```js
const query = cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery(
              "source",
              "source1");

cts.search(query)
  .toArray()
  .map(doc => doc.root.name)
```

You can do something similar with MarkLogic's jSearch API:

```
import jsearch from '/MarkLogic/jsearch.mjs';
jsearch.documents()
  .where(jsearch.byExample({source: {$value: 'source1'}}))
  .map({extract: {paths: ['/name']}})
  .result()
```